# How is this not an answer?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, new-users, specific-answer, first-post-review

I was failing a [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10762200) and I am just wondering why.

I had doubts that this might be on the short side for an answer, but on the other hand, it gives the complete steps in words. The OP is about the same length, asks how to get a map on the value instead of the key field. The answer says: create another map by inserting the value field first, i.e., as the key. Right or wrong, I don't see how that the answer itself is trivial or otherwise not an answer.

Am I missing something here?

**Edit**

I don't think this will be a duplicate of any other question unless it's dealing with the same OP. I've added a "specific-answer" tag to be clear. Also, I am not complaining about the audit system. I'm just interested in this specific first-answer.

**Edit 2**

Again, this is not a duplicate for either cited question, clearly for the reasons I stated. It's about this specific first answer, not any others.

It's one thing whether I did the right thing to think it's an OK answer. It's another whether this is a duplicate meta question. Please consider reopen it.

**Edit 3**

Just to put everything in context:

The Question was:

> I'm looking for a function in C++ that for swap the contents of a map
>   ... that is: those that were the keys now become the items and those
>   that the items were now the keys. Can you tell me if there is
>   something about this?

The deleted first time answer that was supposed to be bad and failed the audit was:

> Insert the items in the map into a multimap - value first, key second,
>   with appropriate comparison function that compares two values of the
>   original map. Once all value-key items are inserted, the multimap will
>   be sorted as intended. Job done!

I may be mistaken, but my reading was that the answer provided what exactly the question asked for, i.e.

> swap the contents of a map

The answer even takes care of the issue that the swapped map needs to be a **multimap** because the values in the original map may not be all unique values. I am kind of sympathetic with the comment left by the answer maker:

> I suggest you read the original question one more time - this time at
>   a slower pace. – Faramarz Dec 8 '15 at 23:20

There was a comment that the above comment is responding to (now deleted) which I was suppose to upvote per the answer and comments here. I think the comment said that this is not an answer or something similar, (hence this question), but I can't see it because of my low rep.

Also, for the third time, my question isn't about my failing the audit per se. It has been about the **specific** deleted question from the very beginning: **How is this not an answer?**

And I don't think all the cited dupes apply to this specific first-time answer.

Comment: By the way, I am banned for 7 days for this and another mistake I made last year. How long should I wait for the penalty status to clear? ie. not get banned for a month next time around?

Comment: He's actually answering a completely different question. OP is asking how to change a dictionary from `{{1,2},{3,4}}` to `{{2,1},{4,3}}`. The answer is dealing with sorting. That being said, it's usually the consensus here that any answer which *attempts* to answer the question regardless of *how wrong or bad it is*, is still a perfectly valid answer - so I don't agree with this audit, either.

Comment: @gnat, I've added a specific-answer tag, just to be clear that this is NOT a duplicate of other meta questions about other answers. I think by definition this is case-by-case.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sorry, what do you mean, exactly? Answers which try to answer a question (even if bad or wrong) are still valid regardless of what queue they're in. And the answerer has already been left a comment to help them improve their post. There really is nothing left to do with the post.

Comment: @Deduplicator There is no reason for him to comment because there is *already* a comment there (visible in the audit itself). The only thing he didn't do was downvote, which I hardly think is reason for a failed audit.

Comment: @Deduplicator No it doesn't. It quite clearly says "No Action Needed when this post needs no action ***from you***.". There is no action needed by tinlyx because a comment was *already left* by another user asking them to improve their answer. It's clear the audit failed because for some reason the answer was deleted (and again, although it was a *bad answer*, it wasn't delete-worthy). The only thing he missed was downvoting, which I don't believe even factors into the audit result.

Comment: @Rob Downvoting very much factors into audit result. If one votes on the post in FP queue, or even upvotes an existing comment, that is already an action. The button "No Action Needed" no longer even applies; it's disabled then.

Comment: Thanks everyone, for the interest in the case. I don't think there is the need to tell each other what to and what not to do. It's not right to do so regardless if I neglected something. @Deduplicator

Comment: @Kendra Thanks. Just did. I get prompted a few times that this is dupe, and either agree with that or edit the question. Hence my edits 1 & 2. Now I think of it, probably I get hinted each time someone vote to close.

Comment: If the answer is incorrect and following the steps mentioned don't lead to an inverted map, should have been at most down-voted. The answer is not harmful, to require deletion, and is related to the question.

Comment: _"Now I think of it, probably I get hinted each time someone vote to close."_ That's correct. You'll see the banner prompting you to edit or agree each time there's a new vote, even if you've already acted on the banner. But _that_ banner is only visible to you, and your question isn't closed yet at that point. I'll go ahead and clean up my previous comment, since it's now obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

The first queue does not ask you whether this is an answer or not; that's what Low Quality queue does. The actions in First Posts queue are more nuanced.  From the description:

> - Vote up or down to rate the question's quality and usefulness
> - Edit to improve the question's appearance or clarity
> - Comment to leave constructive feedback for the author, or vote up existing comments
> - Flag to notify the moderators of serious problems
> - Close questions that cannot or should not be answered here

Two of these actions were appropriate here: **vote down** and **vote up existing comment**. You did neither and failed through inaction.

Comment: I disagree. You made an assertion but probably not much support. I am not convinced that the answer is a bad one for a first-timer and worthy of being used as an audit test. But I get your point.

Comment: @Deduplicator I am not doing this to rescue a first timer if that's what you mean. I am exactly voting on the post. I myself have taken the same approach to generate an "inverse map" in my own programming. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

As terrible of an answer it may be, it's still an *attempt* at an answer.  If you want to use Shog's [apple explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/175248), you could think of this as rotten; it's still an apple but it's not appetizing in the least.

A complete non-answer would be akin to someone posting a link to spam, or posting obscenities in their answer.

The best thing to do would have been to downvote the answer instead.

Comment: This is the first post queue, not low quality's

Comment: @Braiam: You can still downvote content in the first post queue.

Comment: I'm addressing the part of "it's still an attempt at an answer"; nobody doubts it is an answer, but in context it doesn't seems valuable.

Comment: @Braiam:  Yes, that's my point.  It's not valuable, so a downvote would have been preferable to *no* action taken on the post.

Comment: Ohh... I was presuming that you were saying that it was a bad audit.