# How to flag a deleted answer for undeletion for low-rep users

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if there is a proper way to vote to undelete someone else's answer that is deleted.

I came across the deleted answer in question [during a review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10762200), and I believe the answer is deleted incorrectly by the system as explained here [How is this not an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313914/how-is-this-not-an-answer). Outside the review, the question does not exist because my rep is not enough. So I can't see or vote or do anything about the answer.

I just flagged the question instead of the answer, but it's a bit odd as the question itself is not at fault. Hopefully, this will be solved by a moderator.

The more general question is, if there is a potentially incorrect deletion, how does a low-rep user respond?

Note: I looked around meta, this is different from other questions about noting OP to undelete or undelete self-posts.

-- EDIT --

I've attached a screenshot for the deleted answer for information. The answer is deleted so I can't see it except in the audit link. There's no link to flag it.

[image]

-- EDIT 2--

The answer in question has been undeleted by one of the moderators who handled the flag.

Comment: You believe the answer is deleted in error but the consensus [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313919/578411) is that the deletion is correct. The only one disagreeing is you. Anyway, asking on meta is probably one-way to get it un-deleted if users see fit.

Comment: @rene I think one of the two answers there implied that the deletion is in error. `As terrible of an answer it may be, it's still an attempt at an answer... A complete non-answer would be akin to someone posting a link to spam, or posting obscenities in their answer.`;; If you can see deleted contents, you will see that some of the assertions, including the "not an answer" type comment to the deleted answer I was supposed to upvote, got deleted after my question is raised.

Comment: There are many who think I should have downvoted, but I don't see the consensus that the deleted answer is non-answer or should be deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flagging the related question and mentioning that you're actually asking about the deleted answer, as you have done, makes the most sense to me. If you provide the review link or the name of the author of the deleted answer, the moderator processing the flag should be able to figure out what's going on quickly.

If instead you were flagging concerning a deleted question, you could flag some other post by the user who asked the question or even one of your own posts, again providing enough detail to help the moderator find the deleted post you're talking about.

Answer (score 6):

From the review you can get a link to the post (just click "link", in the right sidebar), and the link reveals the answer id<sup>*</sup>, even twice:

```
/questions/7868217/swapping-keys-and-values-of-a-map-in-c/34154476#34154476
```

So you pick this id (34154476). Go to *absolutely any question* and execute this script in the topbar:

```
javascript:$('.flag-post-link').attr('data-postid','34154476');
```

**Note**: after loading the page, **do not** click the "flag" link *before* you executed the script, because the script won't work (reason: jQuery `data` attributes can't be modified once used after the page load, and by clicking the "flag" link, you are accessing the `data-postid` attribute, so the script just does nothing afterwards), and **you'll just flag that "any question" you've opened**, so the flag will just cause confusion. If you did it but not executed the script yet, please reload the page and do all the steps again.

Or if you prefer using console, then remove `javascript:`

This changes the "flag" link of any post on the page, and all of them now open the flag menu of that deleted answer upon clicked.

Then you just click "flag" and select the "other" option, which is the only one because there're no other options for the deleted posts (for any users, including 10k+).

> [image]

You type the reason, submit the flag and the deleted answer is flagged.

Not sure it works? Check in your recent flag summary - https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/683218.

---

* - Also it can happen that the post you want to flag is a deleted question. In this case, there's no hash appended to the url, and it looks like:

```
/questions/1234/have-you-attended-the-csla-master-class
```

In this case you pick the question id (bolded in my example) and any following steps match.

Comment: Thanks. Probably I misunderstand you. I entered just `javascript:$('.flag-post-link').attr('data-postid','34154476');` in the address bar, and then pressed `Enter` in FireFox. But nothing happened. I still can't see the deleted answer.

Comment: @tin you won't see deleted answer. You just execute script and select any answer on the page, or even question itself.

Comment: @tin I've updated the instructions. If you're still not sure whether to use this or not (it will work if everything's correctly done, don't worry), refer josilber's answer.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks. I've attached a screenshot of what I saw about the deleted answer. And this is the one I'd like to vote to undelete. Hopefully, this has the necessary info.

Comment: @Tin read the first step. What does it tell you? To look at the link and extract the id from it.

Comment: @Tin made a small update.

Comment: Sure, this works. However, a workaround (/hack) like this isn't the way to go. Just flag the question the answer was on, and explain the situation in there.

Comment: @Cerbrus Isn't it the way Stack Overflow should be used? ;)